# C program just exits after trying to write to stdout

Tags: c, unix

so written a small function (part of a larger program) and when i run it and input "GET" it exits with a value of 1. to be honest i'm still grasping the concept of open read and write to stdout but not sure what i've done wrong here.

```
int input_arg()
{
    MainStruct val;    //variables are loaded from a config file to this    structure
    char *getInput;
    char *fileInput;
    FILE *loadfile;
    char buffer[1024];
    int n;
    int defaultFile = val.def; //success.txt value read when fileparser.c is run

    printf("http >>  :");
    fflush(NULL);
    fscanf(stdin,"%s", getInput);

    if (getInput == "GET") 
    {
        loadfile = fopen(defaultFile, "r");
        if (loadfile == NULL)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "error loading default resource: PROGRAM WILL EXIT");
            exit(0);
        }
        while ((n = read(loadfile, buffer, sizeof(buffer))) > 0) //reads file  (not sure this should be a while loop)
        {
            if((write(STDOUT_FILENO, buffer, n)) < 0) //writes to stdout
            {
                perror("failed to display file to output");
                close(loadfile);
                exit(1);
            }
        }    
    }
}
```

for compiling purposes the val.def pointer is a string as below

`char defaultFile = "success.txt";`

unsure of what i am missing here. tried changing the structure pointer to a simple char string to see if it was anything there but didn't actually make any difference. i think the problem is with the `while` loop...i don't think it should be there, but i have yet to find an example where a while loop ISN'T used in a write to `stdout` scenario.

thanks

Comment: Variable `getInput` is used before being initialized. It must be set to point to a valid memory address (i.e., of a properly allocated memory segment) before using it (i.e., before passing it to function `fscanf`)!!!

Comment: `fflush(stdout);` instead of `fflush(NULL);` will make it to flush standard output.  Otherwise, it won't print the `"http >> :"` prompt and possibly even crash.  Also try to put some `\n` at the end of messages printed to stderr, or you'll mesh the output.  Also, don't forget to close the file you `fopen()`ed, or you'll be unable to do after subroutine execution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It crashes because you have not allocated any memory for `getInput` to point at. So the program will crash when it attempts to follow the pointer, which will not point to anything useful.

Either allocate memory dynamically with for example `malloc`, or replace it with a static buffer.

Also, you may want to look at `strcmp` for comparing strings. Comparing strings in C with `==` will not compare the strings lexically, instead it will only compare the pointers pointing at them.

Answer (score 2):

```
fscanf(stdin,"%s", getInput);
```

`getInput` is never initialized or allocated memory.Fix it by allocating memory

```
getInput = malloc(200);
```

Comment: And don't forget to test that malloc returned without error and to free the memory when you are done.

Comment: makes no difference if i allocate memory... even after i do. i get the same result. weirdly enough... just exits with value 1. EDIT: just testing something else with malloc. will get back to you

Comment: And don't forget to `free` it. And in general, if you choose to call `malloc` with a constant input value of `200`, you might as well just allocate it statically as `char getInput[200]`. Unless you explicitly emphasize that `malloc` is **just one of the possible ways** to initialize this variable, you should also cover the other options. And in either case, since you've explicitly used `malloc`, you should definitely cover other aspects of this type of allocation (including allocation-failure as mentioned on the first comment, and deallocation at a later point in the execution of the program).

Comment: Hi Barak, yeah i did try that and eventually went with char inputbuffer[100] but am still getting the same result when i run the program. i understand now that i hadn't allocated memory but absolutely stumped as to why it didn't change anything?

Answer (score 1):

Your program has serious issues, the most important one is that you are using `fopen()` with `read()` and that is wrong.

The [`read()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) function takes and `int` as first parameter, which is a file descriptor tha you can create via the [`open()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) function, and not `fopen()` which returns a `FILE *` object, so change<sup>[1]</sup>

```
FILE *loadFile;
```

to

```
int loadFile;
```

and

```
loadFile = fopen(defaultFile, "r");
```

to

```
loadFile = open(defaultFile, O_RDONLY);
```

and then to check for failure

```
if (loadFile == -1) /* it failed to open check errno? perhaps... */
```

you must enable compiler warnings to prevent this kind of mistake, because the first parameter of `read()` in your program is of incompatible type.

The [`fscanf()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) function expects a valid pointer for each `"%s"` specifier, you are passing an unintialzed pointer to it, dereferencing it inside of `scanf()` is undefined behavior.

You need to allocate space for it, something like this should work

```
char inputBuffer[100];
if (fscanf(stdin, "%99s", inputBuffer) != 1)
    thereWasAProblemGettingInput_DoNotUse_inputBuffer_InTheCodeThatFollows();
```

Note that:

1. I used `inputBuffer` as a name for the variable, though this doesn't affect the program execution or compilation at all, the readability matters.
2. Used `"%99s"` to prevent buffer overflow.
3. Checked the value returned by `fscanf()` to make sure that the `inputBuffer` has valid data and was properly initialized.

String comparison in c is not like in many other languages, in your code

```
if (getInput == "GET")
```

is comparing the addresses of `getInput` and the string literal `"GET"`, which will not be the same unless you make `getInput` point to `"GET"`, since you want to compare the contents you need

```
if (strcmp(inputBuffer, "GET") == 0)
```

instead, and do not forget to include the `string.h` header.

---

<sup>[1]</sup><sub>Note that `loadFile` is also a bad choice for a variable name, it feels like a function name, `inputFile` would be more appropriate.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for your input, for some reason didn't work at all and still getting same result. added changes to code though so it's correct and change to srtcmp for string compare.

Comment: @LewisFletch please do not edit the question like that, that invalidates the answers already posted.

Comment: @LewisFletch May be you need to post `main()`.

Comment: oh sorry about that. will change back,,, and sure thing

Comment: `Main()` is basically just calling `input_arg();` at the moment. not doing anything else.

Comment: it still does the same thing and exits after inputting. not sure why but i get the same result. firstly, have i structured this correctly? is it the best way of completing the task?